# Utilizar la funcion COUNT() y un WHERE en el mismo Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(IDPROVEEDORES),
IDPROVEEDOR 
FROM PROVEEDORES
WHERE COUNT(IDPROVEEDORES) > 1
```

Pero me aparece el siguiente error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cuando la condición de filtrado la quieres hacer sobre el resultado de la función de agregación, entonces debes usar la sentencia `HAVING`, no un `WHERE` (esto porque el `WHERE` se usa para filtrar los datos con los cuales se calcula la función de agregación).

En tu caso, debes usar:

```
SELECT COUNT(IDPROVEEDORES), IDPROVEEDOR
FROM PROVEEDORES
GROUP BY IDPROVEEDOR
HAVING COUNT(IDPROVEEDORES) > 1
;
```